# Unable to expose kubernetes dashboard to access it from outside

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I also tried changing kubernetes services yaml file to Node port and then tried exposing the dashboard from the new port i am getting error **"connection is not private"**.So how to access the dashboard by making the connection private?

Comment: Can you provide output of `kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below steps...

1. Undeploy the existing dashboard.
2. Deploy dashboard using the below command:

   ```
   kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/epasham/docker-repo/master/k8s/dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard.yml
   ```
3. ```
   master $ kubectl get svc -n kube-system | grep dashboard
   kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    10.110.127.61   <none>        9090:30000/TCP   2m
   ```
4. `master $ curl 10.110.127.61:9090` ( within the cluster )
5. Access the dashboard from browser using `HOSTNAME:30000`

Comment: working perfectly thanks.but it is not asking the login details